# phpmyadmin is entirely blank Windows 10

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, xampp

I am on windows 10 using chrome but I have tested in edge/firefox as well.

I have installed the latest version of xampp and myphp. When I go to http://localhost/phpmyadmin/ all I get is a blank page... with nothing at all on it.

Also in an unrelated note Apache wont start and complains about port 80 being blocked or unavailable. I don't think that's related but other than what comes with windows 10 I don't have any real extra security installed on the machine.

I'm terrible at this stuff so use small words D: well... at least simple steps :D

Comment: I mention Apache because I am so new at this I don't even know its relevance to my problem only that its part of Xampp.

Comment: are you running skype ?

Comment: @pamirzameen

Okay but will that fix the blank php config screen thing? :O

Answer (score 0):

You can change your Apache port in its config file or you need to stop the services that use port 80.
The common services that use port 80 is Skype or IIS. 
Quit your Skype and restart XAMP if your Skype is on. 
To completely solve this conflict, 
Go to Skype and click on Tools
Then click on Options
Under advanced tab click on connection and then remove the check mark from ***Use port 80 and 443 for additional incoming connections***